# Start topology in WebRTC

Tags: webrtc

I want to implement video chat for many users in one room. I have two options: star topology and mesh topology. In my opinion mesh topology is easiest to implement but for many users in one room probably it will be too slow. I prefer star topology. I'm looking for library/framework which help me to implement proxy server to transfer data between users. I found licode but in my opinion is to high level framework because I create this app for my Engineering Thesis and it can not be too easy...

Answer (score 1):

There are a ton of options for doing this. I agree that star is going to be needed for larger multiway sessions. Any kind of star topology is going to require either an MCU or SFU to process the media. There are some open source options like Kurento (http://www.kurento.org/) and several vendors in this space like Dialogic and Radisys.

In terms of call signaling, I would look at platforms like WebSphere Liberty (www.wasdev.net/webrtc) that include a built in WebRTC gateway and support the SIP servlet programming model. WebSphere also supports JSR 309 which is an interface for media server control. WebSphere Liberty is free for development and small topologies.

In addition, there are a number of open source SDKs for working with WebRTC on the client side. If you like AngularJS checkout the angular-rtcomm module at: http://angular-rtcomm.wasdev.developer.ibm.com/ At this point in time its not showing multiway from this landing page but you can quickly get started building WebRTC apps from there.

Comment: I think that Kurento may be good idea but I wonder if I can implement star topology where one user transfer other users streams and other users send stream only to that user. what do you think about it?